# How to use ensureIndex with geoJSON on node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, indexing, geojson

I'm very new to node.js and mongodb so any help would be appreciated. I have tried using ensureIndex before AND after the collection.update operation but either way it starts erroring out it seems.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    var jsonObj = req.body; 
    var username = jsonObj['Username'];
    var longitude = jsonObj['longitude'];
    var latitude = jsonObj['latitude'];
    var geoJsonObj = {'Username': username, location: {"type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [longitude, latitude]}};

    //res.send(req.body);

    mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
        if (err)
            res.send(null);

        db.collection('catchmerequests', function(err, collection) {
            if (err)
                res.send(null);

            db.collection.ensureIndex( { location : "2dsphere" }, function (err, collection) {

            collection.update({'Username':username}, {$set: geoJsonObj}, {upsert:true}, function(err,result) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(null);
                else
                    res.send(jsonObj);
            });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Running the following code without the ensureIndex works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! You have to call ensureIndex on the database (not the collection), and pass the collection as the first parameter, followed by the index.